# When I want publish Project : "the specified path, file name, or both are too long"

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017, resharper, publish

when i want run or publish a web project, i received this error :

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Cannot evaluate the item metadata "%(FullPath)". The item metadata "%(FullPath)" cannot be applied to the path "jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom\development-bundle\themes\base\images\ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png". The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Someone can help me, Please

Comment: C'mon, dude. Your question and its title already contains an answer: _"The specified path, file name, or both are too long"_. Why nobody reads error messages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't keep your project in deep nested folder.
Try to keep your project in **D:\Projects\YourApp**. In this way your it will not exceed 260 limit.

Comment: It's work but it did not make this error anymore Maybe it's just a short distance to maximum. Thanks for your help

Comment: This limit is **260** symbols for file path and **254** for directory path, not **280**

Comment: Same issues for the long file name. Got stucked for two days and found this solution which works for me. Taking out from the nested directory helps me out to solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

You have reached the maximum path length of the FileSystem. You have to make it shorter, e.g. reducing the filename.

Comment: also you can change your OS, for ex. Windows 10 haven't got this limitation

Comment: [_"for a maximum total path length of 32,767 characters"_](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file).. :D

Comment: True, but this is limitation of NTFS file system, not OS:)

Comment: Got news for you - Windows 10, v1803 *DOES* have this limitation or, to be more precise, NuGet.exe has this limitation which won't be fixed until somewhere in NuGet.exe v5.x. How do I know this? easy, I have this exact same error and came upon this posting as a possible "answer". Unfortunately for me, moving the source tree isn't an option.