# Error deploying to azure app service - "specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be < 260 characters"

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I was trying to deploy my web app to a web app service I created in Azure services portal. I was doing it through Visual Studio Code with the help of Azure extensions (idk if that's important to mention or no). I got this error:

```
"The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters"
```

Unfortunately, I can not change file names or move the project to a different folder. What can I do to fix this issue? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into these SO Threads [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43106223) [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51837306/when-i-want-publish-project-the-specified-path-file-name-or-both-are-too-lo)does this helpful ?

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MSFT yep, looked at them, but for me the long paths were already enabled in settings everywhere, so i'm not sure why i'm getting this error :c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if the below steps help to fix the issue:

1. If it is Node JS Web App, delete the folder called `node_modules` within the project folder. Reload the solution > Rebuild and publish to the Azure. In the Azure Portal > Web App > Console - run the command `npm install` which adds the dependencies within that project with the folder called `node_modules`.
2. If possible, try to move your projects/solutions to the root directory or to the short directory path.
3. According to this [similar issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/issues/234) reported in the GitHub Repo-Azure Web App, you can include a setting in publish profile file like:

```
<PublishTempFolderName>i2</PublishTempFolderName>
```

- Check that reference when using the above setting, some global settings need to be applied given on the GitHub Repo
  (OR) Enable the policy state of `Enable NTFS long paths` in the Local Group Policy Editor and check once.